# How many permutation exists to split a sorted array into two equally sized sorted arrays

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume I have a sorted array of size 2n.
e.g. { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 }
I want to know how many permutations exist that give two sorted arrays concatenated to each other of size n each.

For example in our example:

Permutation 1:  array 1= {1 2 3 4}     , array 2= {5 6 7 10}  **P1={1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10}**

Permutation 2:  array 1= {1 3 4 5}     , array 2= {2 6 7 10}  **P2={1 3 4 5 2 6 7 10}**

Permutation 3:  array 1= {1 3 7 10}    , array 2= {2 4 5 6}   **P3={1 3 7 10 2 4 5 6}**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $C(2n,n)$ ways to select $n$ elements from an $2n$ array.

And another array is automatically created.

Thus, the answer is $C(2n,n)$.